# PHP | weird object behavior, can not call methods

Tags: php, function, oop

so for some reason I'm having troubles with this class I made.
I'm calling 2 simple functions that literally do nothing but echo.
The thing is that one is being called properly, while the other one issues an error.

here are the snippets:
Setter class, assume that the variables are populated (as they really are)
invoker:

```
    <?php

include_once'../classes/Setter.php';
// include_once '../classes/Fetcher.php';

$filter = isset($_GET['path']) ? strip_tags($_GET['path']) : "1";
if ($filter == 1 || is_null($filter)) {
    echo "path is not set";
        return 1;  
}
$path = $filter;
$filter = isset($_GET['fname']) ? strip_tags($_GET['fname']) : "1";
if ($filter == 1 || is_null($filter)) {
    echo "fname is not set";
        return 1;  
}
$fname=$filter;
$filter = isset($_GET['data']) ? strip_tags($_GET['data']) : "1";
if ($filter == 1 || is_null($filter)) {
    echo "data";
        return 1;  
}
$data=$filter;

$setter = new Setter($path,$fname,$data);


echo $setter->sayHi();
echo $setter->sayTest(); //line #35
//echo $setter::sayHi();


?>
```

Class:

```
class Setter {
    private $fileName = "";
    private $path ="";
    private $inputJSON = "";

    public function __construct($path,$fileName,$inputJSON){

       $this->path = $path;
       $this->fileName = $fileName;
       $this->inputJSON = $inputJSON;        
    }
    public function sayHi(){
        echo "path: " . $this->path . "<br />";
        echo 'fName: ' . $this->fileName;
        echo 'inputJSON: ' . $this->inputJSON;
    }
    public function sayTest() {
        echo "tester";
    }

}
```

And this is the output

```
path: data/idc/
fName: cs16inputJSON: { "number": "1", "subject": "testtt", "due" :{ "year": 2015, "month" : 3, "day" : 22 } }
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Setter::sayTest() in C:\xampp\htdocs\CA2\server\ClassAssignmentsSetter.php on line 35
```

any idea ? thought about scoping, nesting.. all that good jazz, but non helped.

thanks!

EDIT:
this is the output for the function  `var_dump(get_class_methods($setter));`

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(11) "__construct" [1]=> string(10) "__destruct" [2]=> string(16) "injectDataAsJSON" [3]=> string(5) "sayHi" } path: data/idc/
fName: cs16inputJSON: { "number": "1", "subject": "testtt", "due" :{ "year": 2015, "month" : 3, "day" : 22 } }path: data/idc/
fName: cs16inputJSON: { "number": "1", "subject": "testtt", "due" :{ "year": 2015, "month" : 3, "day" : 22 } }
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Setter::sayTest() in C:\xampp\htdocs\CA2\server\ClassAssignmentsSetter.php on line 40
```

Comment: Just tested your script and it works fine here, with custom strings set in the constructor.

Comment: apc issues? are you sure you're modifying the right file?

Comment: @Aviad Is this your entire: `Setter.php` script which you show us here or is there more in the class declaration ?

Comment: Your error shows that you are accessing a static function which is not static. So your error either isn't the actual error or you are editing the wrong file.

Comment: @Jordy I have a feeling about the JSON object...wait a sec

edit: nope nope nope

Comment: @Jordy Not true about static method. That's how these errors are displayed. Wrong file editting prolly.

Comment: @Jordy can you tell me what's the differential between both our implementations ?

Comment: @nik Oh yes you are absolutely right about that one, that's pretty weird honestly. Are you sure that you are editting the right class file as nik also said above?

Comment: @Jordy yup... zero clue about wth is going on with this

Comment: put die('here'); in a file where you think Setter class is declared and run again see what happens

Comment: @nik did it, it kills it... the weird thing is that I can invoke "sayHi" as many times as I wish. yet I can not call any other function

Comment: @Aviad Please post an link to an online IDE which produces the error

Comment: Are you using apc? If so try clearing it's cache with apc_clear_cache();

Comment: @nik using XAMPP, can't call this function ...

Comment: What is the output of this var_dump(get_class_methods($setter)); before you call $setter->sayHi();

Comment: @nik 
added this in the main post

Comment: OMFG I was requiring the wrong file.
I'm done with programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason for this might be requiring the wrong file. Happens to everyone =)

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not so clear, do you mean that when you use echo $setter::sayHi(); it's show the Fatal error: Call to undefined method Setter::sayTest() in C:\xampp\htdocs\CA2\server\ClassAssignmentsSetter.php on line 35??

You can't call the method/function using Setter::sayTest(), because in this way you can call static method/function. For call a non static method you have use class object that mean $setter->sayHi() it is the right way of call non static method. Thanks

Comment: Hey, please look at my code.
The error issued doesn't reflect that I used the regular invocation